# Java: Passing a String Variable in new File()

Tags: java, file, filepath, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read a file called list.txt. I created a File called f and passed the string "list.txt" in it. Then I made a String called absolute and stored the absolute path of f in it. Then I created another File called file and passed the String variable "absolute" in it. This however, results in a `FileNotFoundException`. But if I pass the absolute path as a string, meaning without storing it in a variable and then passing the variable, it works. I'm trying to pass the variable String "absolute" into "new File()" and get it to work without getting a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
File f = new File("list.txt");
String absolute = f.getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(absolute); //results in FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: What you are describing does not seem possible. If you print out the absolute path (`System.out.println(absolute)`) does it print what you expect?

Comment: @Unimportant yeah, it prints out the absolute path of "list.txt".

Comment: And you can copy and paste that directly into the `new File()` constructor and it works? Are you able to show what the actual absolute path is?

Comment: Basically, what you are describing doesn't make sense, so we'd have to see some additional code (actual code that you are trying to run) to understand what is going on.

Comment: this is the path: "C:\Users\Tariq\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\GF_4.1\domain1\config\list.txt". I'm trying to read in the contents of the file, store it into an ArrayList, and then print it out (all of which works when I copy and paste the absolute path into the new File() constructor). I'm doing this in Netbeans in a servlet btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the "absolute" value, does it contain the expected one ?

File constructor ( new File(absolute) ) throws NullPointer Exception, only if the passed value in null.

getAbsolutePath() throws Security Exception if the required property value cannot be accessed.

**Check the stored value and the access permissions first.**

Comment: While this is potentially helpful information, I don't know that it qualifies as an answer.